# Accessing <transaction-type> configration of ejb-jar.xml in EJB class

Tags: ejb-3.0, ejb-jar.xml

I have an EJB deployed with configurations in ejb-jar.xml and I would like to access

```
<transaction-type>
```

configurations in my EJB class during ejbCreate() i.e. Bean or Container as I have to pass this value to my framework for internal work.

Note: I do not want repeat and define an additional env-entry for the same as its already there and I would like to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method to determine this information directly.  However, you can get at the information indirectly by relying on the fact that [EJBContext.getUserTransaction](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJBContext.html#getUserTransaction%28%29) throws an exception for CMT:

```
@Resource EJBContext ejbContext;

private boolean isBeanManagedTransaction() {
  try {
    ejbContext.getUserTransaction();
    return true;
  } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Note, the getUserTransaction method cannot be called from all container callbacks (see the table of allowed operations in the EJB spec), but fortunately, getUserTransaction can be called from ejbCreate/PostConstruct, so this method should work for your purposes.